How do I save a buffer from EmacsLisp without being prompted for a filename?
I modified an answer to a recent question to try and save the output to a file. It is going to a buffer, but when it hits the (save-buffer) it prompts me for a filename. I want it to save without a prompt.
Also, the output of (buffer-name) is "EmacsLisp_functions.txt<EmacsLisp>". I am in a directory called EmacsLisp when running this so I don't know if that is what is between < and > .  And finally, the buffer that is created does not show up on MenuBar:Buffers. But it does show up on MenuBar:Buffers:List All Buffers??
(let ()
  (with-current-buffer   (create-file-buffer "EmacsLisp_functions.txt")
    (insert "-------------- EmacsLisp functons: ------------------------\n")
    (insert "Buffer Name: " (buffer-name) "\n")
    (mapatoms (lambda (symbol)
       (when (functionp symbol)
           (insert (symbol-name symbol) "\n"))))
    (save-buffer)))


save-buffer looks at the buffer-local value of the variable buffer-file-name in order to figure out what file to save the buffer to: if it finds that value to be nil, it prompts. You expected create-file-buffer to associate that file with the buffer you created, but it does not: if you check with (buffer-file-name), you'll see that it is nil - hence the prompt. So you need to set that value explicitly (and to an absolute pathname as C-h v buffer-file-name states):
(with-current-buffer   (create-file-buffer "EmacsLisp_functions.txt")
    (insert "-------------- EmacsLisp functons: ------------------------\n")
    (insert "Buffer Name: " (buffer-name) "\n")
    (mapatoms (lambda (symbol)
       (when (functionp symbol)
         (insert (symbol-name symbol) "\n"))))
    (setq buffer-file-name (dired-make-absolute "EmacsLisp_functions.txt"))
    (save-buffer)))

